# g++ cannot find my library

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I'm trying to write a makefile that links my objects.
It successfully has made a dynamic library lib/libunittest.so
 - It's class name was UnitTest.cpp.
When I try to link my mainDriver.o with it it complains:

```
g++ -fPIC -o bin/mainDriver obj/mainDriver.o -Llib -lunittest

Error: cannot find -lunittest
```

Note: I'm doing this on cygwin.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: probably try the absolute path for `-L/<PATH>/lib` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a problem with the *.so file type as you are running this on Window. Change that to *.dll and it should work.